# Some dlls missing in TFS 2018 server

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015

I installed TFS 2015 in a Windows Server 2012 R2 machine.

I noticed that in this machine I had some dlls like for example:

```
Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.WindowsForms.dll
```

Now I installed TFS 2018 in another machine, but I cannot find that dll.
Why is that?

Comment: Some components get merged and some are renamed, shouldn't be surprising on such a version jump. also there shouldn't be the need for a *.windowsforms.dll on the server anyway, thats way this isn't there anymore. there should be a "Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory" somewhere i think

Comment: I was asking because I had some scripts referencing that dll. So, I should still have it :) Otherwise I'll get errors using them.